# Internal Server Error com arquivo .htaccess Linux mint

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, htaccess

Estou recebendo um erro HTTP 500 **Internal Server Error** no linux mint, servidor Apache.

> Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) / Server built:   Apr  3 2014 12:20:28

arquivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Qual a solução?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Módulo desativado

Provavelmente o seu Apache2 não está com o módulo Rewrite ativado.

Digite `ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/ | grep rewrite` e cheque se aparece rewrite.load, se aparecer significa que o módulo rewrite já está instalado e basta ativa-lo, para isso digite o seguinte:

```
a2enmod rewrite # Ativar o módulo
service apache2 restart # Reiniciar o servidor
```

Se não tiver aparecido um rewrite.load quando você deu `ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/ | grep rewrite` então o mod_rewrite não está instalado, procure como instalar o mod_rewrite no Linux mint (provavelmente deve ser do mesmo jeito que Ubuntu)

## AllowOverride

Agora temos que falar para o Apache2 permitir alterações, através do *AllowOverride*. Navegue para o diretório de sites do Apache2

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

digite `ls` e veja qual site quer editar, **provavelmente** será o *000-default.conf*. Partindo com o presuposto de que esse seja o nome:

```
mcedit 000-default.conf
```

(substitua mcedit pelo seu editor favorito, como nano, gedit ou geany).
E edite todos os AllowOverride para *AllowOverride All* se não tiver nenhum AllowOverride no 000-default.conf edite o arquivo **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**
e procure por algo assim:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

E substitua desse jeito:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

## Previnir o .htaccess de dar erro 500

Você pode previnir o erro 500 alterando o seu arquivo .htaccess para só fazer as ações se o módulo rewrite estiver ativado, para isso altere seu arquivo .htaccess assim:

```
# Checar se o modulo esta ativado
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Já existia o rewrite.load, ativei-o, segui os outros passos, mas ainda assim não funcionou...

Comment: Ah, consegui, exclui a linha que tinha:  AllowOverride AuthConfig, e tudo funcionou, obrigado!!

Comment: Essa serviu pra eu resolver no Windows, obrigado!