# Internal Server Erro com arquivo Htaccess

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Tudo começou quando eu mudei do EasyPHP para o VertrigoServ, o arquivo .htaccess funcionava perfeitamente no EasyPHP , mas aqui estou encontrando esses problemas... não faço ideia de como resolver isto...

HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Response:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: Provavelmente mod_rewrite não foi carregado. Verifique se está ativado no Apache. Mas se quer saber melhor o motivo do problemna, leia o log de erros do Apache.

Comment: Easyphp, xampp, wamp, vertrigoServ são tudo apenas pacotes e facilitadores de instalação, seu problema ainda é com o Apache, você mesmo já fez uma pergunta sobre o assunto, no VertrigoServ é a mesma coisa, ele usa apache portanto siga as dicas da resposta aqui [Internal Server Error com arquivo .htaccess Linux mint](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25396/internal-server-error-com-arquivo-htaccess-linux-mint) Entenda como uma critica construtiva =)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro ao instalar script em localhost](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149169/erro-ao-instalar-script-em-localhost)

Answer (score 1):

Se isto fizer o erro desaparecer seu módulo REWRITE não está ativado.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Ative o módulo conforme as instruções do seu servidor.

Comment: O -1 não é meu, mas tem alguma coisa estranha na formatação/texto... confira se está de acordo com minha edição.