# Erro ao instalar script em localhost

Tags: php, apache, localhost, htaccess

Estou tentando instalar um script em local host, porém aparece o seguinte erro:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@localhost to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

acredito que o erro é ocasionado pelo arquivo .htaccess, só não sei como modificar ele.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tenta remover o .htaccess pra ver se funciona (faz backup antes). Você consegue citar o error.log do Apache?

Comment: Sim, já apaguei o arquivo .htaccess, porém o site fica sem formatação e perde suas funcionalidades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

já tive este problema, provavelmente você está usando um daqueles programas que provém PHP, Apache, MySQL juntos. Como você está manipulando URL em seu arquivo do tipo `apache` você deve habilitar o módulo de reescrita, que se localiza em:

Você deve localizar o arquivo `httpd.conf` do seu servidor Apache, e procurar pela seguinte linha:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Retire o `#`, que significa comentários, ou seja, a linha está comentada; salve o arquivo e reinicie o seu servidor, provavelmente o erro `Internal Server Error` deixará de aparecer.

Se você usa `WAMP` como eu, clique sobre o ícone dele na bandeja, vá em Apache, depois no arquivo que eu disse o nome e realize as alterações descritas anteriores.